# Understanding summation formulas

Tags: summation, computational-complexity, constants

[Can someone help me to understand what is going on here because I have some misunderstanding about some summation formulas of constant](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCHLx.png)

1) Why we can write this constant summation like below? Some explanation and citation.

$$\sum_{k=j+1}^{n-1}c=\sum_{i=m}^{n}1={n-m+1}$$ 
Step 1) $$\sum_{k=j+1}^{n-1}c={(n-1)-(j+1)+1}={n-1-j-1+1}={n-j-1}$$

Step 2)
$$c\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}({n-j-1)}=c\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\left[\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}n - \sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}j-\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}1\right]$$

Step 3) For each summation in brackets we continue:

$$\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}n = n\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}=n((n-1) - (i+1)+1) = n(n-1-i)$$

$$\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}j = \sum_{i=1}^{n}i=\frac{n^{2}+n}{2}=\frac{(n-1)^{2}+n-1}{2} = \frac{n^{2}-n}{2}$$
At this point I don't understand why is there some other result for this one like:

$$\frac{(n-1-i)(n+1)}{2}$$

Some table of formulas and examples for problems to find big-Oh notation would be perfect.

Comment: You dropped the constant at many places. This should be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* The representation $\sum_{k=j+1}^{n-1}c=\sum_{i=m}^{n}1={n-m+1}$ is not admissible.

> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> T(n)&=\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\color{blue}{\sum_{k=j+1}^{n-1}c}\\
> &=\color{blue}{c}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\color{blue}{\sum_{k=j+1}^{n-1}1}\\
> &=\color{blue}{c}\sum_{i=0}^{n-1}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n-1}\color{blue}{(n-j-1)}
> \end{align*}

Here is a slightly different derivation which might ease calculations.

> At first we observe that the upper limits $n-1$ lead to factors $n-1$ during the calculation. This can be simplified if we calculate $T(n+1)$ instead of $T(n)$. The formula for $T(n)$ can then be easily derived from $T(n+1)$.
>
> We obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{T(n+1)}&=\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n}c\\
> &=c\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}\sum_{k=j+1}^{n}1\tag{1}\\
> &=c\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=i+1}^{n}(n-j)\tag{2}\\
> &=c\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i-1}(n-j-i-1)\tag{3}\\
> &=c\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i-1}j\tag{4}\\
> &=c\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2}(n-i-1)(n-i)\tag{5}\\
> &=\frac{c}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n}(i-1)i\tag{6}\\
> &=\frac{c}{2}\left[\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)-\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)\right]\tag{7}\\
> &\color{blue}{=\frac{c}{6}\left(n^3-n\right)}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we factor out the constant $c$.
- In (2) we calculate the inner sum.
- In (3) we shift the index of the inner sum to start with $j=0$.
- In (4) we change the order of summation of the inner sum $j\rightarrow n-i-1-j$.
- In (5) we calculate the inner sum by recalling *[Faulhaber's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula#From_examples_to_matrix_theorem)*.
- In (6) we again change the order of summation of the inner sum $i \rightarrow n-i$. More detailed:
  \begin{align*}
  c\sum_{i=0}^{n}\frac{1}{2}(n-i-1)(n-i)
  &=\frac{c}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n}(n-i-1)(n-i)\\
  &=\frac{c}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n}(n-(n-i)-1)(n-(n-i))\qquad\qquad\qquad [i\rightarrow n-i]\\
  &=\frac{c}{2}\sum_{i=0}^{n}(i-1)i
  \end{align*}
- In (7) we again use Faulhaber's formulas.

Comment: Thank you I get it around here, what are the next steps after this?

Comment: @MrRobot: You're welcome. I prefer a different, more elegant derivation. I could add it to the answer if you are willing to delve into some details. After mastering it you will also be able to follow the derivation in the paper.

Comment: Dear Markus, that would be very helpful, If it is easy for you I can accept the solution in a good writing paper.

Comment: @MrRobot: Calculation added. With it you might also be able to verify the calculations in the paper.

Comment: I want to ask you in (4) how the (n-j-i-1) become j ?

Comment: Thanks, also in (5) what about Faulhaber's formulas? Si the basic one as I can see is $\sum_{i=1}^ni = \frac{n^2+n}{2}$ in our case this is $\sum_{j=0}^{n-i-1}1 = \frac{(n-i-1)^2 + n-i-1}{2}$ right?

Comment: Yes, but I can't understand from (4) to (5) how did u calculated to get the $\frac{1}{2}(n-i-1)(n-i)$ ?

Comment: $\sum_{j=0}^{n-i-1}j = \frac{(n-i-1)^2 + n-i-1}{2}=\frac{n^2-2ni-2n+i^2+2i+1+n-i-1}{2}=\frac{n^2-2ni-n-i^2+i}{2}$ is this correct? If yes, how do you get from here the result $\frac{1}{2}(n-i-1)(n-1)$

Comment: Please can you explain to me at (6) how did you get the result $(i-1)i$ I understand that we can put before summation known variables like $\frac{1}{2}$ but what do we get after that? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @MrRobot: Details in comment section added.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!

Comment: @MrRobot: You're welcome.

Comment: Where can I find something to understand better this part of changing the order of inner summation?

Comment: @MrRobot: Good question. I recommend reading chapter 2: *Sums* in *[Concrete Mathematics](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~r97002/temp/Concrete%20Mathematics%202e.pdf)* by R.L. Graham, D.E. Knuth and O. Patashnik (and now it's time to upvote this answer :-)).

Comment: I would really like to do so but my reputation is under 15 and I can't do it yet!

Comment: @MrRobot: Ah, I see. No worries, thanks.

Comment: I will do it after I get the reputation. Thank you so much for your explanation!